# Load SDF (.model) into robot_description

Tags: gazebo, sdf, xacro, ros-fuerte, robot-description

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the past and currently, you can load a URDF/XACRO file into the parameter service via something like:

```
<param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro.py 'my_robot.urdf.xacro'"/>
```

The latest Gazebo package supplies several nice robot models (simulator_gazebo/gazebo/gazebo/share/gazebo-1.0.1/models/youbot.model for example) which are great to spawn in Gazebo. Is it possible to use the .model file (in the SDF format that Gazebo uses) in order to load the model into robot_description in Fuerte?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33628/load-sdf-(.model)-into-robot_description/) by [rtoris288](https://answers.ros.org/users/982/rtoris288/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1173 on 2012-05-09

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe the robot_description parameter can only handle Collada and URDF formatted files. This is then read by the "URDF Interface" for use with tf, Rviz, etc. A SDF .model file is not supported.

---

Originally posted by [Dave Coleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1279/dave-coleman/) with karma: 1396 on 2012-06-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should be able to set the robot_description with a SDF file as:

> `<param name="robot_description" textfile="$(find <my_robot>)/model.sdf"/>`

---

Originally posted by [ffurrer](https://answers.ros.org/users/3149/ffurrer/) with karma: 115 on 2012-10-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2017-04-27**:
This answers directly to OP indeed. But then after reading in SDF as a parameter, you'll probably need it to be processed by `robot_state_publisher` as [this answer](https://goo.gl/NtEy9I) explains, which isn't [supported yet](https://goo.gl/CZNPCc).